# Extract type ICollection<> from return type Task<ICollection<>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I use the following method to obtain some Data from the DataBase:

```
  public async Task<ICollection<Medikation>> GetMedikamentTask(string dbId)
  {
     var medikamentSet = await _medikationApiService.GetMedikationSet(selector, dbId);

     var responsefiltered = medikamentSet.Results.Where(c => c.Result != null).ToList();
     return responsefiltered[0].Result.Medikation;
  }
```

responsefiltered is Type List<> but since I have to work with async/await, my return type should be wrapped in a Task<>.
The thing is that on the following GetMedikament method I use methods like taskLists.Any or OrderByDescending, so I have to become a ICollection as answer..

```
public WebhookResponse GetMedikament(WebhookRequest request, string dbId, int? mediId = null)
      {
         var taskLists = GetMedikamentTask(dbId);
cut code....
          }
```

I tried to not use async method, and called .Result, but that isn´t the proper way to solve this. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: The *correct* way is again: `await`; does it work OK if you change to `public async Task<WebhookResponse> GetMedikament(...)` and `await` it? (`var taskLists = await GetMedikamentTask(dbId);`). There is no magic way of calling async methods from sync methods.

Comment: But than I have my WebhookResponse wrapped in a Task<>

Comment: That is the behaviour of `async` methods, whether we are happy with it or not. It will usually result in propagating even as far as to the main function making it an `async Task`, but that is okay in most cases. If you are however still interested in ways to trick this behaviour, then you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/13524307)

Comment: @FelipeLivingstone yes! yes you will; `async` is infectious

Comment: @Quacke I´m afraid that´s my case... My main function should return just a WebhookResponse... not a Task<>, I still don´t know how to work that :/

Comment: @FelipeLivingstone I have edited the answer below to provide you with more options, check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if you use an `async` method in another method this second method will also become `async`, so consider changing your `GetMedikament` method to something like:

```
public async Task<WebhookResponse> GetMedikament(WebhookRequest request, string dbId, int? mediId = null)
{
     var taskLists = await GetMedikamentTask(dbId);
     // do stuff
}
```

If you don't want that or cannot do that, then there's a disclaimer: trying to trick `await/async` is risky because your app may encounter a deadlock (a thread can get stuck and the app might freeze).

You can still try to do it if you must and there are [entire articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#vertical-partitions) on how to, but still, there is some risk and/or compromises involved.

In your case the [thread pool hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-thread-pool-hack) (offsetting the work to a different thread) seems appropriate and safe enough. This will not cause a deadlock, but you can't modify the UI inside the function (which won't be a problem here).

the function would look like this:

```
public WebhookResponse GetMedikament(WebhookRequest request, string dbId, int? mediId = null)
{
     var taskLists = Task.Run(() => GetMedikamentTask(dbId)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     // do stuff
}
```